# Onload function for change style doesn't work

Tags: javascript, function, styles, onload, getelementbyid

Well, i want that when body is completely loaded then call a function for show a hide image. I tryed a lot of things and searched a lot but anything work. I think it's pretty simple and easy but i don't know why doesn't work...I wish that anyone be able to help me.

```
<body onload="start()">
<div id="bg" style="display:none"></div>
</body>

function start() {
document.getElementById("bg").style.display = 'block';
}
```

[Here Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Uwt64/319/)

Comment: That's because in your jsfiddle javascript settings you have it set to run the functions onload. http://jsfiddle.net/mt0wpb0z/ Also no need for the jQuery library since this is using vanilla javascript. You could also use this method http://jsfiddle.net/1fcunueq/

Comment: please put your javascript code to the <script></script> tag,before the end of the 'body' tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to option:

**1- add script at  before starting**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Add your code here to run after fully page load
        document.getElementById("bg").style.display = 'block';
    });
</script>
```

**2- or add your script at end of `<body>` before ending `</body>` tag:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     //Add your code here to run after fully page load
     document.getElementById("bg").style.display = 'block';
</script>
```

Comment: Or place the script tags in the `<head>` and use `window.onload=function(){}`

Answer (score 0):

just remove onload="start()" from your body and replace your function start for

```
<script>
    window.onload=function() {
        document.getElementById("bg").style.display = 'block';
    };
</script>
```

if you want use jquery, then

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#bg").css("display", "block");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to run your Javascript inside the `body` tag. Actually at the end.
Conversely, the `start` function will be undefined and nothing happens:

```
<body onload="start()">
    <div id="bg" style="display:none"></div>
    <script>
        function start() {
            document.getElementById("bg").style.display = 'block';
        }
    </script>
</body>
```